# Display attachment resolution size

Tags: attachments, images

Seems rather easy, but there is no article I can find on the web or in Wordpress about it.
 How to simply display (in the current post) the full image size (of the attachment), in pixels?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [`wp_get_attachment_img_src( $attachment_id )`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)  function returns an array consisting of:

- The URL to the img
- width
- height

To get the actual attachment/thumbnail/featured image ID, you want to use

```
$att_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() );
```

in the loop. Outside the loop, you would have to get the Post ID somehow to feed it in as `get_the_ID()` refers to the currently looped post object which isn't present there. The whole call would look like this:

```
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) );
printf(
    'Image size: %dpx &times; %dpx (%s)',
    absint( $img[1] ),
    absint( $img[2] ),
    is_bool( $img[3] ) AND $img[3]
        ? 'cropped'
        : 'uncropped',
);
```

The result would display as:

> Image size: 600px × 320px

Comment: thanks, but it displays 0px x 0px. I'm using your code, in the loop.

Comment: @whitelord How did you add that image? Is it the featured image? And have you tried it with one of the default themes and all plugins turned off?

Comment: the image it is a featured image, yes. I uploaded it while I was in the post, so it is attached to the post. I have no problems using other codes to call the attachment in the post, so the problem is with your code.

Comment: @whitelord Please tell me the output of the following: `var_dump( get_the_ID(), get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) );` in your loop (right before the code in the answer).

Comment: in a random post: `int(283) string(3) "284"`

Comment: @whitelord Ok? So if that actually outputs the IDs, I need to see the contents of `var_dump( $img );` (right below the first line in the answer).

Comment: `array(4) { [0]=> string(111) "http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/my-image-150x100.jpg" [1]=> int(150) [2]=> int(100) [3]=> bool(true) }`150x100 is the size of the thumbnail present on the post, but I want the size of the full image.

Comment: @whitelord The array keys are actually numeric - thought they were associative. Should work with the edited answer now and also states if the image is cropped. If you don't want that, you will have to remove that part yourself.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' (refers to the last one)

Comment: @whitelord Oh, dear. Then just [edit] the answer and fix it. This is WordPress _Development_ at least...